# SQL suddenly fails to generate a user instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I have an application deployed to Windows Server 2016 VM on IIS, using SQL Express.

It has been working perfectly all day, but suddenly I am seeing this error when trying to log in:

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in copying database files. The connection will be closed.

This is after making no changes to the code or `web.config` whatsoever.

I have tried these solutions already:

- Restart SQL service and Delete all contents in `C:\Users\SKotze\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS`
- Add `User Instance=true` to the connection string
- Ran this bit of SQL before restarting the service:

  ```
  exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1.
  GO
  Reconfigure
  ```

This is driving me crazy I just dont't understand why it suddenty stopped working.

Please let me know if I can provide any further details.

My connection string:

```
<add name="WebEntities1" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is the disk almost full or perhaps the user's quota almost used up? I assume you actually do need to use user instances - your connection string is not using AttachDbFileName so it looks like you don't need to: [SQL Server Express User Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances).

Comment: 1) Check disk space  2) check memory available  3)  Reboot the machine when the issue occurs to see if that fixes it  4)  Probably should do some logging to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The app is still being developed so no one is actually using it right now, so your first suggestions are almost certainly not the issue. I only tried the user instance settings because I have lost all hope - I have no idea if I need it or not. Probably not though because I could log in without any issues only 2 hours ago..